# Matching whole words with Javascript's Regex with a few restrictions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that can extract all words from a given string that only contain alphanumeric characters.

```
Yes
yes absolutely
#no
*NotThis
orThis-- 
Good *Bad*
1ThisIsOkay2 ButNotThis2)
```

Words that should have been extracted: Yes, yes, absolutely, Good, 1ThisIsOkay2

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/B2T1DS/2) is the work I have done thus far:

```
/(?:^|\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\b|$)/g
```

I had found [this](http://rubular.com/r/kWrdNwWmqg) expression that works in Ruby ( with some tweaking ) but I have not been able to convert it to Javascript regex.

Comment: A simpler regex to try to adapt would be [`(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/Zjn1Ka/2). The trouble with it is that there's a look-behind (which JS doesn't support).

Comment: `\b` matches between a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non-word character **or** the limits of the string. So writing, `(?:^|\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\b|$)` is exactly the same than writing `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/(?:^|\s)\w+(?!\S)/g` to match 1 or more word chars in between start of string/whitespace and another whitespace or end of string:

```js
var s = "Yes\nyes absolutely\n#no\n*NotThis\norThis-- \nGood *Bad*\n1ThisIsOkay2 ButNotThis2)";
var re = /(?:^|\s)\w+(?!\S)/g;
var res = s.match(re).map(function(m) { 
  return m.trim(); 
});
console.log(res);
```

Or another variation:

```js
var s = "Yes\nyes absolutely\n#no\n*NotThis\norThis-- \nGood *Bad*\n1ThisIsOkay2 ButNotThis2)";
var re = /(?:^|\s)(\w+)(?!\S)/g;
var res = [];
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^|\s)`  - either start of string or whitespace (consumed, that is why `trim()` is necessary in Snippet 1)
- `\w+`  -  1 or more word chars (in Snippet 2, captured into Group 1 used to populate the resulting array)
- `(?!\S)` - negative lookahead failing the match if the word chars are not followed with non-whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that *(where `s` is your string)* to match all the words:

```
var m = s.split(/\s+/).filter(function(i) { return !/\W/.test(i); });
```

If you want to proceed to a replacement, you can do that:

```
var res = s.split(/(\s+)/).map(function(i) { return i.replace(/^\w+$/, "@");}).join('');
```